# set a variable to a negative value on mousedown

Tags: javascript, variables, mousedown

in my code right now i've got a lot of strings and dots which are getting pulled to the position of my cursor but what im trying to do right now is that when i do a mouseclick that the variable changes to a negative value so the strings and dots are getting pushed away.
Im new to JS and i simply dont know how to Code that.

```
var c = 1000;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', back);
physics.makeAttraction(mouseParticle, myCurrentParticle, c, 100);
function back(){}
```

i dont know if thats enough code for you guys if theres more needed pls tell me.

Comment: "when i do a mouseclick that the variable changes to a negative value"  Which variable are you talking about?

Comment: variable c right now defines how big the attraction to the cursor is so c should switch to -1000 and then again to 1000 if the mouse is pressed again and so on and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply your value by -1 in the function to swap the sign.

```js
var c = 1000;

let d = document.getElementById('num')
num.innerText = c

function back() {
  c *= -1
  num.innerText = c
}
```

```html
<span id="num"></span>
<button onclick="back()">reverse</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You yould utilize the Math.sign() method to check if the value of c is positive or negative and act accordingly.

```
function back() {
  if (Math.sign(c) > 0) {
    c = -1000;
  } else {
    c = 1000;
  }
}
```